# vs 2015 professional blend, can not open cloud service project

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, cloud

I installed
New visual studio 2015 professional blend on new windows 10, and cannot open windows azure cloud service project, it appears as (incompatible).

Also, I can't find web project templates while open new project.

Comment: Have you installed Azure SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Yes azure SDK version 2.81 for vs 2005

Comment: Now I have a web templates, but still the azure cloud service project sign as incompatible in the solution explorer.